# Reconstructing data sent over the network in UWP apps via streams

Tags: networking, uwp, datagram

I'm experimenting working with streams in UWP to send data from one machine to another over the network.

On the sending machine, I created a DatagramSocket and serialize the data I want to send into bytes and write that to the output stream.

On the receiving machine, I create another DatagramSocket and handle the MessageReceived event to collect the sent data.

This appears to be working in the sense that when I send data from one machine, I do receive it on the other.

However, the data I'm serializing on the sender is a size of say 8150 bytes, which I write to the stream.

On the receiving end, I'm only getting about 13 bytes of data instead of the full load I expected...

So it appears that I'm responsible on the receiving end for reconstructing the full data object by waiting for all the data to come in over what might be multiple streams...

However, it appears that I'm getting packets 1:1 -- that is, if I set a breakpoint right before the send and right after the receive, that when I write and flush the data to the output stream and send it, the receiving end then triggers and I get what seems to be partial data, but I never get anything else.

so while I send 8150 bytes from the sending machine, the receiving end only gets a single packet about 13 bytes in length...

am I losing packets? it seems to be a consistent 13 bytes, so perhaps it's a buffer setting, but the problem is I the 8150 bytes is arbitrary; sometimes it's larger or smaller...

I'm obviously doing this wrong, but I'm so new to network programming I'm not really sure where to start fixing this; on a high level what's the proper way to send a complete memory object from one machine to another so that I can reconstruct an exact copy of it on the receiving end?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out that the problem was that when I was writing to the output stream on the sender machine, I was using a regular StreamWriter and sending it the array as an object:

```
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(output);
            writer.Flush();
        }
```

I believe this ends up writing the object itself using ToString() so what I was actually writing to the stream was "byte[]" or whatever the type was...

Instead I replaced this with a BinaryWriter and write the full output array and the complete contents are now received on the other end!

```
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(output);
            writer.Flush();
        }
```

I know this wasn't very well put together, but I barely know what I'm doing here :) still i hope this might be helpful to others.